# everything got superbig after sudden poweroff in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, shutdown

After power went off unexpectedly and my desktop got off , i turned it on and ubuntu starting page came on which i usually don't ever see ! then some logs went on really fast indicating that somethings went wrong and then when desktop came up it was all like the screenshot i included here , hope you can get me a solution fast , thank you .
my ubuntu version is 20.04 . i tried changing the resolution on my display settings but the only option available was 640*480 (shown in the screenshot)

[image: screenshot of my system]

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card? In that case you may have to reinstall the graphics drivers. Go to `Additional Drivers` in Software & Updates, and see if some driver is available.

Comment: there is a graphic card (NVIDIA corporation: GF108[GeForce GT730]) and is using the recommended driver : NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-390(proprietary , tested)

Comment: Try disabling and reinstalling that driver

Comment: What is a version of currently running kernel? Have you tried to boot with previous kernel version?

Comment: no i did not , tried reinstalling the graphic driver , said you should restart , so i restarted and now nothing comes up ! just a blank page with a blinking underline -_-

Comment: yes i have access to terminal now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if dedicated gpu is detected via `lspci | grep VGA` ,if you get an output then you have corrupted drivers and need to  reinstall it (nvidia or amd or intel have linux gpu drivers).

Edit: Try typing in the command  sudo ubuntu-drivers install ,  note that some nvidia gpu is EOL (340 series needs kernel 5.4 , if you want to run it) .

> This Linux 340 legacy driver series has provided extended support for the G8x, G9x, and GT2xx GPUs

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller : NVIDIA corporation GF 108 [GeForce GT 730](rev al)

Comment: as i said in the comments above , tried reinstalling the driver (although from software and updates) it required a restart so i give it one and now nothing comes up just a blank page with a blinking line

Comment: Press ctrl + alt + f2 , see if you can get into terminal? , or any of the function map ,eg ctrl+alt+f3...f4 , if so then its xorg config issue

Comment: yes i can get into terminal

Comment: log into your account by typing user name and  password in terminal

Comment: yes i have done that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118371/discussion-between-binaryops20-and-sepehr-damavandi).

Comment: Please edit the answer to add the solution, which is only available in chat. It may immensely help someone in future.